# Possible to share OAuth access tokens between V2 and V3?

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I have Companies I authenticated with against V2. With V3 on the scene, can I safely make V3 API calls with their same tokens? Or do I need to have all of my users re-authenticate themselves?

I would think they are re-usable but during the run-up to V3 I vaguely remember reading/hearing some documentation which suggested otherwise. And I don't want to muck anything up by actually trying it out (it would be **bad** if Intuit somehow set a flag upon a V3 API call saying "this Company is now V3-enabled, disable V2" or something to that affect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tokens are the same, only the actual REST endpoints changed.

There is no need to get new tokens.